# Resource and asset merger: The file name must end with .XML

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin, webview

Hey guys I am trying to make webview in a flutter. So I used the flutter review package and later I came across an error with  Clear text not permitted. Then I created a .xml file in android res folder with some code that fix the above code. Now when I am trying to build the apk it gives me a strange error saying the file name must end with.XML
Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add the following in the manifest file of the auto-generated Android folder: `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`?
You should add this inside this tag: .

By adding this, the error with "Clear text" should be gone. Also consider a flutter clean and flutter pub get after making the change.

The .xml error sounds like the you didn't create the file correctly. When creating files do not forget to add the extension correctly.